# apacheとフレームワークで起動するサーバの違い

Tags: apache, flask

**環境**
Mac os
vagrantにubuntu14.04を仮想で起動し開発しています。

**問題**
webサーバソフトウェアのapacheとフレームワークのFlaskの違いを教えてください。

現在、ローカルの環境でFlaskを使いwebアプリを動かしているのですが、apacheなしでもwebサーバを起動して動かすことができます。

調べると、apacheは普通のパソコンをwebサーバーにするソフトであり、ブラウザから要求が来た時に、htmlを返すということだとわかりました。
ですがapacheなしでFlaskだけでもブラウザでアクセスした時に、htmlを返すアプリは動きます。

なのでapacheの必要性がよくわかりません。
詳しい方教えていただけないでしょうか？

実際のサーバにアプリを上げて動かす時には必要だということでしょうか？

Comment: Flask内蔵のサーバーは主に開発時の利便のためです。スレッドもサポートされているので小規模なサイトなら運営可能かも。大量のアクセスを捌くためにロードバランスするとか、複数のWSGIアプリを同時に走らせるとか、アクセス制御とか、一部のURLだけ書き換えるとか、多少込み入ったことをするならApache/Nginxを使った方が良いです。

Comment: わかりました。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。質問を解決にしたいのですがコメントでの回答だとできないです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11181145571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントでもかかれていますが、Flaskに付属しているサーバーは、あくまでも開発用ですので、

- Apache等と比べるとパフォーマンスがかなり悪い
- 複数リクエストが同時に来たときの挙動が怪しい

等があり、本番で使ってはいけません。

Flaskアプリを動かせるサーバー(WSGI)はいろいろありますので、ここを参考に選んでみてください。個人的には手軽なGunicornやuwsgiがオススメです。
https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html